# When using contains keyword in Selenium while finding element, it displaying below error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, contains

When using contains keyword in Selenium while finding element, it displaying below error:

> Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression: Xpath=//*[contains(@name,'add-to-cart')]
> TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.

In both element declaration, it was not detecting the element :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@name,'add-to-cart')]")
WebElement addToCartBtn;

OR

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@name,'add-to-cart')]")
WebElement addToCartBtn;
```

**Note :** When define with full name as below, then element is found and continue execution

```
@FindBy(name = "add-to-cart-sauce-labs-fleece-jacket")
WebElement addToCartBtn;
```

[Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T512q.png)

Comment: Check if the element is not in the iframe. If not, then use `explicitWait` for it

Comment: Thank you @YaDavMaNish, for responding. Actually Element was available with name as "add-to-cart-sauce-labs-backpack", if i consider full name, element was detecting and execution is continued, here i want to consider only the "add-to-cart" only.

Comment: Ok so can you try with the `//*[starts-with(@name,'add-to-cart')]` I'm not sure why it is not working for you

Comment: @YaDavMaNish, still no improvement. It behaves as above and displaying error.

Comment: Ok, try with the //button[contains(@name,'add-to-cart')]

Comment: @YaDavMaNish, still same response but i tried with css selector, it was executed successfully. Thank you for your response.

@FindBy(css = "[name^=add-to-cart]")
WebElement addToCartBtn;

Comment: can you share the URL for it let me check it

Comment: Url :
https://www.saucedemo.com/

Username : standard_user
Password : secret_sauce

Comment: Remove "Xpath="... should be something like : @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@name,'add-to-cart')]")

Comment: Your failing because (after logging in) there are 6 items that match `"//*[contains(@name,'add-to-cart')]"`  - but you are using `@findBy`  on a single `webelement` - you are telling your code to expect only 1.  What are you trying to do? What do you want you script to do?

Comment: @RichEdwards, i want to find first element that match with name as "add-to-cart", because in this page, all buttons consists of item names, i dont want that items names...So i want to select only item that contains in top

Comment: If you blindly want to select the first element try `@FindBy(xpath = "(//*[contains(@name,'add-to-cart')])[1]")`